# Nginx multiple location redirect not working

Tags: nginx

I'm trying to redirect my URL for a plugin inside the bitbucket app to a different url through nginx but for some reason the when i go into that location it is still into the bitbucket app but not to the jira app.

nginx version that i'm using is 1.12.2 (i know its very old, but cant do much)

```
server {
    listen          443;
    server_name      bitbucket.mycompany.com;

    ssl                     on;
    ssl_certificate         /etc/nginx/ssl/bitbucket.mycompany.com_certnew+intca.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key     /etc/nginx/ssl/bitbucket.mycompany.com_pkcs8.key;
    ssl_session_timeout     5m;
    ssl_protocols                   TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers                     HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers   on;

    # Optional optimisation - please refer to
    # http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/configuring_https_servers.html
    # ssl_session_cache   shared:SSL:10m;

    location = /plugins/servlet/jira-integration/issues/* {
            return 301 https://myjira.atlassian.net/browse/$1;
    }

    location / {
            proxy_pass          http://localhost:7990;
            proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Host $host;
            proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Server $host;
            proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_redirect      off;
    }
```

}

So if i go to the URL https://bitbucket.mycompany.com/plugins/servlet/jira-integration/issues/ABC-3330 i'm expecting as per nginx config it should redirect to https://myjira.atlassian.net/browse/ABC-3330 but instead it is in the same URL as bitbucket.mycompany.com

Comment: There is no wildcard `*` syntax for Nginx [location statements](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location). What is `$1` supposed to represent? Is it everything following the `/issues/`?

Comment: Yes everything after /issues/... Will remove the * and see if it works

Comment: No luck even after removing *

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a regular expression to capture the end of the URL into `$1` so that it can be used in the subsequent `return` statement.

For example:

```
location ~* ^/plugins/servlet/jira-integration/issues/(.*)$ {
    return 301 https://myjira.atlassian.net/browse/$1;
}
```

See the [documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) for the `location` directive.